# How to Create login module of admin (only signIn) and validate user in spring without spring security?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, swagger

created the entity of admin.

```
public class Admin{
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String password;
}
```

used getter and setter, constructors and completed entity.

further not able understand?

how to create a login admin?
what should be added in AdminRespository, AdminService, AdminController to validate user?
without using spring security.

Comment: What examples have you checked already? Please show your attempts

Answer (score 0):

create a method in JPARepository to fetch all users details from database  then pass that data to html or thymeleaf then you can write if condition to check if that particular user with that password exist in data or not if exists login success if not then login fails.

Refer to below links:-
To fetch data-https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spring-boot-how-to-access-database-using-spring-data-jpa/

To Pass data to thymeleaf-https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-list

To write if conditions in thymeleaf-https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/how-to-implement-if-else-in-thymeleaf-with-spring-boot